# How to fetch a div's id with data- value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how can I fetch a div's id according to its data- value with jquery

for example how can i grab the first div's id value with data-type of comment or if the data-type was post, how would i grab that id attribute value?

so far i came up with this jquery but it only gets the first div's id instead of getting the first div with data-type="comment"...

**my jquery :**

```
var getFirstPostID = $("#divwrap").find(".post_wrap").data("post-type", "comment").attr("id");
```

**div's :**

```
<div id="divwrap">
    <div id="1174" data-type="post" class="postwrap"></div>
    <div id="1151" data-type="post" class="postwrap"></div>
    <div id="1100" data-type="post" class="postwrap"></div>
    <div id="1042" data-type="comment" class="postwrap"></div>
    <div id="1018" data-type="comment" class="postwrap"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of _so_ many threads.

Comment: point me to a direction because i couldnt find one @Nit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy

```
$('#divwrap').find('div[data-type="comment"]').attr('id')
```

Comment: would this grab the first div's id with data-type of comment?

Comment: nice well let me try it out.

Comment: @this.Tony I've updated it to be a little safer in case there are no matching divs found. `attr` will return the attribute value for the first element in the set of matched elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()` after `.find()` and you would just need to get the `id` prop:

```
$("#divwrap").find(".post_wrap").filter('[data-type="comment"]').prop('id');
```

```js
var getFirstPostID = $("#divwrap").find(".postwrap").filter('[data-type="comment"]').prop('id');

alert( getFirstPostID );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divwrap">
    <div id="1174" data-type="post" class="postwrap"></div>
    <div id="1151" data-type="post" class="postwrap"></div>
    <div id="1100" data-type="post" class="postwrap"></div>
    <div id="1042" data-type="comment" class="postwrap"></div>
    <div id="1018" data-type="comment" class="postwrap"></div>
</div>
```